# In the Linux kernel, why does the SIGCHLD signal not interrupt the wait() system call?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals, waitpid

Consider a scenario like this: The parent process calls `wait()` to wait for the child process to exit, and the signal handler is registered for `SIGCHLD`. When the parent process blocks at `wait()`, the child process ends, at which point the parent process receives a `SIGCHLD` signal (regardless of setting special fields).

After I tested, I found that `wait()` was not interrupted by the SIGCHLD` signal to fail and return -1, but returned successfully after executing the signal processing function. Why is that?

Comment: GNU/Linux is an OS, whereas Linux is just a kernel

Comment: How, specifically, is the signal handler registered?  What `sigaction()` or `signal()` call is used?

Answer (score 1):

[man wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

> **ERRORS**
>
> **EINTR**: WNOHANG was not set and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was caught

Since you've established a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, `wait` does not get interrupted.

---

For more info, see: [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), especially:

- Waiting for a signal to be caught
- Synchronously accepting a signal
- Signal mask and pending signals

  > A signal may be blocked, which means that it will not be
  > delivered until it is later unblocked. ...
- Execution of signal handlers
- Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers

  > If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:
  >
  > - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or
  > - the call fails with the error EINTR.
  >
  > Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and whether or not the signal handler was established using the SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)). **The details vary across UNIX systems; below, the details for Linux.**
  >
  > If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is
  > interrupted by a signal handler, then the call is automatically
  > restarted after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call fails with the error EINTR:
  >
  > - wait

Comment: ”then the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used“，but I didn't set the SA_RESTART field.
Perhaps the Linux implementation implicitly restarts the wait() in this case?

Comment: @meowrainy Do you use `sigaction`? What do you specify in the `sa_flags` field? Furthermore: _"depends on the interface and whether or not "_, i am not sure. Based on your description, it seems, that `wait` gets restarted (assuming you didn't set the `SA_RESTART` flag).

Comment: @meowrainy `signal(7)` mentions, that the behaviour can vary between unix systems, but for linux,it states that the SA_RESTART flag gets considered (as can be read above, i've added the relevant section - in bold). It seems further research is needed.

Comment: Your quote from the `wait()` manual page does not support your claim "Since you've established a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, `wait` does not get interrupted."  On the contrary, it suggests that `wait()` would be interrupted by a `SIGCHLD` *even if that signal were blocked*.  The rest of this manual is relevant, but also does not explain the specific behavior the OP asks about.

Comment: Also, I can replicate the OP's reported behavior both with `SA_RESTART` in effect and without, and I can confirm that on Linux, `wait()` *does* respond to `SIGCHLD` even when that signal is blocked (but the handler, if one is registered, does not run if the signal is blocked).

Answer (score 0):

> After I tested, I found that `wait()` was not interrupted by the SIGCHLD` signal to fail and return -1, but returned successfully after executing the signal processing function. Why is that?

Well, if the signal handler ran while the thread was blocked in `wait()` then that call *was* interrupted.  I guess the question is why `wait()` then went ahead with collecting the child and returned successfully instead of failing with `EINTR`.

I can reproduce that behavior.  The specifics of how you register the handler are unclear, but in my tests I see the handler running and `wait()` thereafter returning successfully even when the `SA_RESTART` flag is not set for `SIGCHLD`, which is generally a major factor in whether restartable system calls such as `wait()` fail with `EINTR` when interrupted by a signal.

I'm having trouble locating any documentation that specifically prescribes the observed combination of results for `wait()` + handler function + `SIGCHLD`, but the bottom line is that `SIGCHLD` is special.  In particular, it has a special relationship with `wait()`, because the events that a system-generated `SIGCHLD` reports on are exactly the ones that a blocking `wait()` call is waiting for.  Some of the manifestations of that specialness are

- The `sigaction()` function defines two flags modulating behavior related specifically to `SIGCHLD`, and *none* specific to any other signal.
- Even though the default disposition of `SIGCHLD` is documented as `SIG_IGN`, its actual default behavior is unique to that signal and distinct from the behavior obtained by explicitly setting the disposition to `SIG_IGN`.
- POSIX has special provisos for the behavior of the `wait`-family functions, as described in the notes in [the `wait()` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html), about how these functions are affected by the disposition and flags associated with `SIGCHLD`.

I don't think either POSIX or Linux explicitly says so, but it all comes around to a pending `SIGCHLD` being how the `wait`-family functions recognize that there is a child to collect.  POSIX is sufficiently unspecific that I think other POSIX systems could do it differently, but to the best of my knowledge, using `SIGCHLD` for this purpose is both traditional and what Linux does.  Enough so that signal-handling behavior is specifically designed to accommodate the common behavior of using `wait()` *inside a handler for `SIGCHLD`* to provide for central processing of terminated children.

It is also notable that `wait()` will collect the child and clear the pending `SIGCHLD` even if that signal is blocked, analogously to how `sigwait()` will receive blocked signals.  In that case, any registered handler is bypassed.

---

Your case of establishing a handler for `SIGCHLD` that does not collect the status information for the child is unusual, but consider what needs to happen here:

- a `SIGCHLD` has been received, it is not blocked, and a signal handler has been registered for it, so the signal handler must run and the `SIGCHLD` must be removed from the pending list.
- after your particular handler runs, the status information for the child has not yet been consumed, so it must be consumed when control returns to `wait()`. Otherwise, it can *never* be consumed and reported, for receipt of a `SIGCHLD` is how the system is triggered to do that, and the context in which the status information is delivered.

I anticipate that your `wait()` would fail with either `ECHILD` or `EINTR` if the signal handler collected the waited-for child via its own `wait()` call.  Which one depends in part on whether the `SA_RESTART` flag is set for `SIGCHLD`.  I anticipate that it would fail with `EINTR` if there was a running child, and the `wait()` was interrupted by a synthetic `SIGCHLD`, and the `SA_RESTART` flag was not set.